# Bluemix / Liberty / Eclipse - Console proxy: error connecting to IP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

Eclipse Neon with Bluemix Liberty Plugin and WLP tools installed is throwing the following error at the Eclipse console (every 5 seconds):

```
proxy: error connecting to 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: dial tcp 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: i/o timeout
proxy: error connecting to 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: dial tcp 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: i/o timeout
proxy: error connecting to 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: dial tcp 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: i/o timeout
proxy: error connecting to 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: dial tcp 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: i/o timeout
proxy: error connecting to 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: dial tcp 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: i/o timeout
proxy: error connecting to 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: dial tcp 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: i/o timeout
proxy: error connecting to 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: dial tcp 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: i/o timeout
proxy: error connecting to 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: dial tcp 75.126.XXX.XX:8081: i/o timeout
```

Note: The log doesn't actually show X's in the IP, the full IP has been hidden.

The error started right after adding and removing a second WLP server instance using the WebSphere Liberty Tool plugin. Is it possible to fix it at the configuration side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a temporary issue with the loggregator service. It should be working fine now.